# Auto submitting Checkbox to save to MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, checkbox

I have a page on my website with a 20 checkboxes for each user that has an account, i want to be able to submit the checkbox when it is changed to save it to a DB. Its hard to explain, but i will attach screenshots of the code, HTML output and DB:

PHP code to get the boxes is:

```
<?php  
for ($x = 1; $x <= 16; $x++) {
            $result0 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM View WHERE `UserID` LIKE '" . $x . "'");
            while($row0 = mysqli_fetch_array($result0)) { 
                if($row0['20']=="1"){$checked = "checked";}else { $checked = "";}}
echo "<td class=\"align_center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"20_" . $x . "\" " . $checked . "/>
";}
?>
```

[image: checkboxes]

[image: html output]

[image: DB]

Im hoping someone can help! PLEASE!

Thanks

Comment: Are all checkbox in form? if right, you can using jquey to get event `click` to submit form

Comment: @L Barnard why is this less than equal to `for ($x = 1; $x <= 16; $x++)`

Comment: Mr Ken, can you procive code?

Comment: Pavan Baddi, this is how it added the multiple columns of checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

The below ajax request would trigger on each checkbox change event.

You will need a PHP script to recieve the data and update your DB.

Look [Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: "someFileToUpdateDB.php",
    data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
    success: function(){
      console.log("Change saved.");
    },
    error: function(request,status,error){
      console.log("ERROR: "+error);
    }
  });

});
```